# How to prompt user for a proper writable file in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: files

I need to prompt the user for a file which is 1) not a directory 2) if already exists, is writable.

I know I can use `read-file-name`, but I'm not sure how to filter out the improper files. Specifically, I need to filter out those are either 1) a directory or 2) read-only (not writable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6th argument to `read-file-name` is a `PREDICATE` that filters completion candidates (file names).  `C-h f read-file-name` says, about it:

> Sixth arg `PREDICATE`, if non-`nil`, should be a function of one
>   argument; then a file name is considered an acceptable completion
>   alternative only if `PREDICATE` returns non-`nil` with the file name
>   as its argument.

The file name passed to the predicate is a relative name, so your predicate function may need to use `expand-file-name` to obtain an absolute file name. Then you will want to apply function `file-directory-p` to each candidate, to see if it's a directory, and apply function `file-attribute-modes` to each candidate, to see if it is writable.

See also [(elisp) File Attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Attributes.html) for info about function `file-attributes` (search for `file-attribute-modes` in that manual node).

Comment: Thanks, I thought there will be a hidden pre-baked solution somewhere given this need seems to be common.